# Upload_data not working for Google App Engine tutorial using remote_api

Tags: android, python, shell, google-app-engine, remoteapi

I am trying out the Google App Engine tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/) and I am stuck at the "Upload Places Simulated Data" section. After much changes, I finally made the command start uploading data, but where the prompt should come for email password, nothing is coming at all - it is just stopping - process is continuing endlessly.

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Google/google_appengine
$ ./appcfg.py upload_data --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename places.csv --kind=Place -e nobody@nowhere.com
02:13 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20150426.141322
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
```

Tried changing the email "nobody@nowhere.com" with my own email Id, but still the same.

New with server/backend so did lot of reading including SO forums ([Google App Engine and Upload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357511/google-app-engine-and-upload-script)) but could not find this issue anywhere! Please help - stuck since 2 days

Comment: The dev server does not need a password. The bulkloader is still working, but all docs are gone. If you like a prompt? Remove the e-mail address from appcfg. Maybe the e-mail is not even needed.

Comment: @voscausa, Yes, I tried removing the email completely as well, and still the same result - it gets stuck after the above shown steps and does not move to saving in DB, uploading items part. I triple checked that my bulkloader, places.csv etc are correct as well - totally confused here.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to work now when I tried using the exact same command in Windows cmd (open as Admin) but it still does not seem to work in cygwin! How is that possible? Why is it not working in Cygwin? Any ideas @voscausa ?